# IOS Gamecenter Leaderboard : Multiple score entries for single player

Tags: iphone, game-center, leaderboard

I have a simple query about Apple's gamecenter leaderboards. 
Is there a possibility of making multiple score entries for a single player?? Example, I have a score of 100 first and then i score 200, I need both the scores to be displayed for me on the leader board. Is it possible?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible with GameCenter, the Gamecenter leaderboards only pick the highest

You should create your own leaderboard and server to get what you want or maybe with openfeint

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we have our own database. still we were looking for the same functionality in Apple's Gamecenter also.